# Elasticsearch 5.2.2 Raspberry pi 3 low cpu memory optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, raspberry-pi

I have successfully installed elasticsearch-kibana 5.2.2 on arm raspberry pi 3 but I get 100% of all cpus.
Except max memory, shards and replication is there any other settings I can apply for low resource machines?
For example, threads and max cpu cores or something else as optimization?

Answer (score 1):

You should note that elasticsearch needs a lot of CPU time on startup, so CPU workload is at 100% for the first ~30s (measured by me on a Cubietruck).

If you want to do sth. about it you could make the elasticsearch process [nicer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)).